# How to auto refresh list of session array items on submit?

Tags: php, arrays, submit, refresh

I am working on a school comparing website. For this I need a plugin that handles that function. I save session data as school IDs so it can be passed on in the comparing table after choosing the schools.

Tasks that I have trouble with:

1. "Add button" - add post/school ID to session array - $_SESSION['schools']
2. Dashboard at the top - echo $_SESSION['schools'] values (just for user experience list the schools that are currently in the list)
3. when "Add button" is pressed  update the dashboard list automaticly. Preferably not the whole page.

My attempt so far:

First of all I have I commented PHP form action:

```
    <?php   session_start();    
    $schools = array('post_id');

    //If form not submitted, display form. 
    if (!isset($_POST['submit_school'])){

    //If form submitted, process input.
    } else {
        //Retrieve established school array.
        $schools=($_POST['school']);
        //Convert user input string into an array.
        $added=explode(',',$_POST['added']);

        //Add to the established array.
        array_splice($schools, count($schools), 0, $added);
        //This could also be written $schools=array_merge($schools, $added);

    }

    $_SESSION['schools'] = $schools;
?>
```

Next up is the form itself:

```
    <form method="post" action="http://henrijeret.ee/7788/temp_add_button.php" id="add_school">
    <input type="hidden" name="added" value="Value" size="80" />
    <?php
        //Send current school array as hidden form data.
        foreach ($schools as $s){
            echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"school[]\" value=\"$s\" />\n";
        }
    ?>
    <input type="submit" name="submit_school" value="Lisa võrdlusesse" />
</form>
```

And for the dashboard I use:

```
    <?php


    foreach($_SESSION['schools'] as $key => $value){
        // and print out the values
        echo 'The value of $_SESSION['."'".$key."'".'] is '."'".$value."'".' <br />';
    }
?>
```

This is just a prototype to get my head wrapper around the task ahead of me...

**Problems**
Something does not feel right.. :P

When I submit the form, then the first change is not made. When I press it the second time, then it will update the the list leaving out the very last string. When refreshing then whole page, then the last one pops up

I very appriciate the advice on this long topic.. Maby I do not know where to look, but I am a little stuck with searching a solution..

Link to my running code http://henrijeret.ee/7788/

Answer (score 0):

You're submitting the form on the first run.. if you will check it your URL changes and on the next run.. since you got this

```
  //If form not submitted, display form. 
    if (!isset($_POST['submit_school'])){

    //If form submitted, process input.
    } else {
        //Retrieve established school array.
        $schools=($_POST['school']);
        //Convert user input string into an array.
        $added=explode(',',$_POST['added']);

        //Add to the established array.
        array_splice($schools, count($schools), 0, $added);
        //This could also be written $schools=array_merge($schools, $added);

    }
```

it will go to else statement because POST is already set.

Try this:

```
 //If form not submitted, display form. 
    if (!isset($_POST['submit_school'])){

    //If form submitted, process input.
    } else {
        //Retrieve established school array.
        $schools=($_POST['school']);
        //Convert user input string into an array.
        $added=explode(',',$_POST['added']);

        //Add to the established array.
        array_splice($schools, count($schools), 0, $added);
        //This could also be written $schools=array_merge($schools, $added);

       $_SESSION['schools'] = $schools;

    }
```

Comment: It still behaves the same way - http://henrijeret.ee/7788/ .

Can I somehow prevent it from changing the url? I did not notice that... It looks like it could be the problem here... But I do not know what the solution would be..

Maby some jQuery/ajax stuff would work? At first glance i did not find the right solution with jQuery..

Comment: if you want stop your form on submitting , you may put something like this in your script `$('input[type="submit"]').click(function(){
$("#add_school").submit(function(){ return false; })});`